# recursively rename files and remove a character

Tags: linux, bash, rename, xargs

There are some file names which contain '?' 
As you know windows has problem with such characters. I want to recursively rename all files in the folders using `xarg`. For example

```
09 - grand hall?_10.mp3
```

should be

```
09 - grand hall_10.mp3
```

Comment: while you're at it, do you want to remove spaces?

Comment: it isn't bad. What to do then?

Comment: and does the solution _have to_ use `xarg`?

Comment: do any of the directories include spaces or `?`?

Comment: I don't know. I thought I have to use xargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for file in $(find folder -name '*.mp3'); do

   mv -v "$file" $(echo "$file" | tr ? _);

done`

---

The above has whitespace issues; this is better:

`find folder -name '*.mp3' -exec echo "'{}'" \; |

  while read file; do

     echo -n "mv -v $file " && echo $file | tr ? _;

done | sh`

The idea is to find all the files, then echo them in quotes.  Pipe the output into a `while` loop that constructs a `mv` command for each file, and then pipe *that* into a new shell.

Ugly, but if you don't like the answer, you shouldn't have asked the question.  :-)

Comment: spaces are causing noise. what to do to remove them?

Comment: @AdamLiss I've fixed a couple of minor issues with whitespace in `$file` in this, but it's still got re-tokenizing issues with `for file in $(find _folder_ -name '*.mp3')`. You might want to try something based on a `find -print0` piped to a `read -d ''`

Comment: @je4d Tokenizing is fixed, formatting is as intended.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AdamLiss closer.. but filenames can technically contain newlines, the only watertight way to pass the list around is will `null` delimitation. You've also introduced a code execution issue, as I could make a filename like '`file$(my code to run)name`', and your pipe to sh will end up running `my code to run`!

Comment: Just as a curiosity, will single-quotes handle newlines correctly? And your file names have newlines in them, you're fired.  :-)

Comment: @AdamLiss Not in general.. filenames can contain single quotes as well ! To fix it, first avoid piping to `sh`, that's almost always a bad idea. Use `find ... -print0` to print your filenames separated by null bytes. Then pipe that to a `while read -d '' filename; do ...; done` loop. The `-d ''` makes the `read` use null-byte delimitation.

Answer (score 2):

This is terribly ugly, but I took it as a personal challenge to find a one-liner that would work.  :-)

`find folder -name '*.mp3' -exec \

   sh -c "echo -n 'mv \"{}\" ' && echo \'{}\' | tr ? _" \; | sh`

The strategy is to find the files, use `echo` to construct a `mv` command for each file with its name in quotes, and then pipe the output to a shell.

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @mahmood: Fixed.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: This is the most elegant answer to this question yet. Thanks!

Comment: @Bicou: for some definition of "elegant," perhaps.  :-)  Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should work even if filenames contain single/double quotes and spaces:

```
(IFS=\0;find . -name \*\\?\* -type f -print0| while read -d '' f;do mv -v $f $(echo $f|tr -d \?);done)
```

Explanation:

1. `find` only search files whose names contain '?'
2. setting `\0` as delimiter in `IFS`, `find`(by `-print0`) and `read`(by `-d ''`) can handle filenames containing special characters like single quotes, double quotes, spaces, etc.
3. the outmost parenthese puts the entire command execute in subshell, hence keeps the current shell's `IFS` intact.
4. The `.` in the script could be replaced by any other directory.
5. This script has a very tiny catch, though: it may break if both a file's name and one of its parents' name contains '?'. This could be handled, but the script will become a little uglier and less readable.